# Is There a Way To Register Services.AddDbContext In ApplicationBbContext Out-Side The Program.Cs In DotNet 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

The Repository Failed To Construct Because The
DbContext
Does Not registered.

> ApplicationDbContext

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
 
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
}
```

```cs
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

Comment: "Register Services.AddDbContext In ApplicationBbContext Out-Side The Program.Cs In DotNet 6" What do you mean? Do you want to register DbContext with service in the startup not Program.cs or what?

Comment: In DotNet 6 There Is no **startup** . I didn't want to register DbContext or use  ` using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`  in **program.cs** . 
Is that possible to separate API from DAL?

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate the implementation to an extension method like this:
Create a class in another file:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyDBContexts(this IServiceCollection services,string connectionString)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
          //Add any DbContexts here
            return services;
        }
    }
```

Then in your program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ServiceProvider provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
builder.Services.AddMyDBContexts(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```